How to hide menu items on mobile when clicked
I'm working on a one-page WordPress website and the page scrolls to each section when a menu item is clicked. It works well on desktops/laptops but on mobile devices when the hamburger menu is tapped, the menu opens and it blocks the screen. I would like to hide the dropdown menu list/section only on mobile. At the moment I have to close the menu by tapping on "X" close button.
I have searched for a solution and I found some JS code here in Stackoverflow but it has not worked.
Here is the JS code:
<script>
  function closeFunction()
  { 
     document.getElementById('bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').style.display='none';
  }
</script>

I'm not so experienced in JS but with some guidance I fix this, please help.
Screens:


You can simply make an event listener, and hide it.
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Function to close the menu
    function closeMenu() {
      var menu = document.getElementById('bs-example-navbar-collapse-1');
      menu.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the menu
    }

    // Get all the menu links
    var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 a');

    // Add click event listeners to all menu links
    menuLinks.forEach(function(link) {
      link.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
    });
  });
</script>

